# How to receive files in Binary mode in PureFTP

Tags: pureftpd

I have created a new Linux server with **Pure-FTPD** as a FTP server

Whenever I transfer text files from a Windows PC using FileZilla to Pure ftp server running on Linux, the *text file undergoes corruption or modification* , which after some web search I found to be CR and LF (Carriage Return and Line Feed) related changes in Windows and Linux as in [here](https://support.microfocus.com/kb/doc.php?id=7008378)

The **FileZilla** transfer mode was set as **Auto** , after doing some web search , I found that when transfer mode is set to or is in  ASCII mode this problem might arise.

A temporary solution is to **set Transfer mode as Binary in Filezilla** which did solve the problem.

But I want to manage this Transfer mode of Binary at the Receiving side (within Pure FTP server) permanently instead of setting Transfer mode as Binary in Filezilla.

I tried setting Pure FTP config with "disable_ascii" set as yes as suggested [here](https://www.novell.com/documentation/open-enterprise-server-2018/oes_implement_lx/data/bn0rvzm.html#b117rwyg)
, but this did not work.

Are there any other methods to set Pure FTP to receive files in Binary mode only even though if the clients send it as ASCII?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the vendor documentation from https://download.pureftpd.org/pub/pure-ftpd/doc/README

They somewhat agree with you:

> ASCII transfers are hell, because
> they are consuming CPU time both at client and server sides. And they even
> consume *more* bandwidth than binary transfers. But they allow Windows
> clients to upload scripts to Unix servers, stripping these nasty <kbd>^M</kbd> signs.

Disabling ASCII support appears to be possible, although not with a runtime configuration directive, it appears to have to be disabled  at build time with a configure switch:

```
   ------------------------ ADVANCED COMPILATION ------------------------


The "./configure" script accepts some arguments you might want to add before
the compilation:

...

/-----------------------
 "--without-" switches
 -----------------------/


--without-ascii: does not support 7-bits transfers (ASCII) .  If you have
customers using Windows clients to send scripts and HTML files, don't use
this option or they will yell at you.
```

Comment: I have been through the  documentation, so  disabling ASCII at runtime configuration is not possible ? .  "disabled at build time " -  is that the only option ,  since the server has been setup and reinstalling the Pureftp is a bit out of range now.  Is there any other options ?                
Thanks , I will look into this.